# Don't See Fork Command In GitHub Anymore

Tags: github, github-issues

In my GitHub page whenever I visit someone's repository, the **Fork** button which used to be there has now changed to **Code** button which basically downloads the code instead of forking to my repository. Why is this so, is there a limit to how many projects I can fork in GitHub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea where you are looking at. When I'm logged in on github and look at a repo I see a *Fork* button on the very top right.

[image: Top right of a github repo-page]